# Counting results filtered by distinct() or group_by() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, postgresql

I want to count my results of an active record query with CI (using postgreSQL). I am using `count_all_results()`, which works fine for most queries, but not when using `distinct()` or `group_by()` after a join, because `count_all_results()` ignores these functions.

Here is a fix vor this, which is not yet implemented in the newsest (2.1.3) stable version.
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/commit/b05f506daba5dc954fc8bcae76b4a5f97a7433c1

When I try to implement this fix in the current version myself, there is no additional filtering done. The row count stays the same.

Any tips on how to implement this in the current version, or other ways to count results filtered by `distinct()` or `group_by()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    $this->db->select('COUNT(id)');
    $this->db->join();
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->group_by();
//...etc ...
    $query = $this->db->get('mytable');

    return count($query->result());
```

or

```
    $this->db->join();
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->group_by();
//...etc ...
    $query = $this->db->get('mytable');

    return $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: or return $query->num_rows()?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$this->db->group_by();
```

otherwise

```
$this->db->distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using Codeigniter 3.1.11 as of today, distinct() *is* taken into account when doing count_all_results(). HOWEVER you have to use the function, doing a $this->db->select("distinct x") and then the counting, won't apply the DISTINCT limitation for the record count.

Answer (score 0):

Enjoying the syntactic sugar that Codeigniter offers can be:

```
return $this->db->distinct()->select('non_unique_column')->count_all_results('your_table');
```

or

```
return $this->db->select('DISTINCT non_unique_column')->count_all_results('your_table');
```

But bear in mind that the rendered SQL will be (with some variation based on your db driver):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "numrows"
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT non_unique_column
FROM your_table
) CI_count_all_results
```

If your result set doesn't need isolate distinct values because the results will be guaranteed to be unique anyhow, then you can simply use:

```
return $this->db->count_all_results('your_table');
```

This simpler code will produce the following rendered SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "numrows"
FROM "STL_PROPERTYME_PORTFOLIO"
```

Regardless of your implementation, `count_all_results()` will always return a non-negative integer without having to explicitly reference a column by name.